# Defining a column in an excel file using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How do I select a column in an excel file and display it only by pandas
I tried:

```
    videos = df.loc[:, df.columns == 'videos']
    videosvar = (videos.loc[num].values)
    print(videosvar)
```

Comment: You just want to show just one column in pandas? `df['column_name']` is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select column by directly mentioning the column name.

```py
videos_column = videosvar["videos"]  # returns the column as a series
```

Answer (score 1):

If need select by indice and column name use:

```
videosvar = df.loc[num, 'videos']
```